# Creating a Callback function in Python and C++ with Boost

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm trying to do something and I'm not sure if it's possible. I have a C++ dll library which I'm wrapping in another dll to allow it to be accessible from Python.

In the C++ side I need to register callbacks with the signature

```
int __cdecl CallbackHandler(int type, const char* val)
```

and then I register the function like this:

```
CallbackRegister(TYPE_ENUM, CallbackHandler);
```

I am using Boost::Python to try and wrap this so ideally I would like to be able to register a callback in Python and have it called whenever new messages come in, so that all the values are given to me in Python.

Is this even possible or am I barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Take a look at Cython instead. It makes C++/Python interoperability relatively painless.

Comment: Thanks - I did have a look but it seemed way more complex. I'll give it another look.

Comment: So you want the implementation of the given callback to be a python function? I'm thinking one generic C++ callback that dispatches the python functions stored in a std::map<int, boost::python::object> and a function to register python functions in this map (this one you'd expose to python). It's a pity the callback handler doesn't provide a parameter for user data.